# Flutter: Bouncing button animation scroll issue

Tags: flutter, animation, button, dart

I want to add some **smooth** & **fluid** animations in my Flutter app, especially on **buttons** like these on the [Reflectly](https://reflectly.app) app (made on Flutter too).

So I **followed** [this tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-bouncing-button-animation-ece660e19c91) to add **Bouncing Animations** on my buttons. Everything is working fine but I noticed a "*bug*" related to the scroll:

When I touch a button **AND** keep pressing it, then **drag** to scroll down or up (**always by keeping down**), the button **keep the down state** and **do not return** to it's original position (see the GIF for more details).

*Note: This issue **doesn't appear** on the **Reflecty** app.*

[image: bug video]

To reproduce, this "*bug*", you can download the Bouncing [button project](https://github.com/dancamdev/article_bouncing_button_animation) here and then create a scroll with some bouncing buttons inside it like this:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              AnimatedButton(),
              // [...] Many others animated button here 
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I tried to add a `onVerticalDragEnd` callback to restore the state after but it's **worse** because it is **no longer possible to scroll** (scroll seems to be catches only on buttons) !

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
When `onTapDown` and scroll will trigger `onTapCancel` 
You can put `_controller.reverse();` in `_onTapCancel()` 
code snippet

```
void _onTapCancel() {
    print("on tap cancel");
    _controller.reverse();
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimatedButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnimatedButtonState createState() => _AnimatedButtonState();
}

class _AnimatedButtonState extends State<AnimatedButton>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  double _scale;
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      lowerBound: 0.0,
      upperBound: 0.1,
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
    _controller.forward();
  }

  void _onTapUp(TapUpDetails details) {
    print("onTapUp");
    _controller.reverse();
  }

  void _onTapCancel() {
    print("on tap cancel");
    _controller.reverse();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _scale = 1 - _controller.value;

    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: _onTapDown,
      onTapUp: _onTapUp,
      onTapCancel: _onTapCancel,
      child: Transform.scale(
        scale: _scale,
        child: _animatedButtonUI,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get _animatedButtonUI => Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 250,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Color(0x80000000),
              blurRadius: 30.0,
              offset: Offset(0.0, 30.0),
            ),
          ],
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            colors: [
              Color(0xFFA7BFE8),
              Color(0xFF6190E8),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'tap!',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              AnimatedButton(),
              AnimatedButton(),
              AnimatedButton(),
              AnimatedButton(),
              AnimatedButton(),
              AnimatedButton(),
              AnimatedButton(),
              AnimatedButton(),
              AnimatedButton(),
              AnimatedButton(),
              AnimatedButton(),
              AnimatedButton(),
              AnimatedButton(),
              AnimatedButton(),
              AnimatedButton(),
              AnimatedButton(),
              AnimatedButton(),
              AnimatedButton(),
              AnimatedButton(),
              AnimatedButton(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```